# Amplitude Spectrum of FM wave from Bessel First order

Tags: modulation, frequency-modulation

given the values for \$\beta=5\$, for the Bessel of the first order:

\$ J_{0}(5)=-0.26, J_{1}(5)=0.34, J_{2}(5)=0.49...\$

in order to plot the amplitude spectrum of the FM wave, do you treat the negative numbers as absolute?  The \$ J_{0}(5)\$ amplitude should be \$ |J_{0}(5)|\$ ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a frequency component has negative amplitude, it means 180 degrees phase shift for that component. If you only compare component strengths, it's ok to use absolute values.